# Selenium Grid2 : parallel tests run on the same browser at the same time

Tags: selenium, testng, selenium-grid

I've got two nodes with same configurations(Win7, ie9). I set testNG to execute two tests one each node at the same time. Selenium Grid does open two browsers(one each node) at the same time, but the tests seem to be executed in just one browser -- the username is typed in in the same browser twice. And if I set `thread-count=1`, both tests succeed.

The testNG test suite xml file:

```
<suite name="ExampleTest" parallel="tests" thread-count="2"> 
    <test name="ExampleTest1">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.mycompany.testsuites.GridTest">
                <methods>
                    <include name="test1"></include>
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="ExampleTest2">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.mycompany.testsuites.GridTest">
                <methods>
                    <include name="test2"></include>
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
```

The test class GridTest :

```
public class GridTest {

    private WebDriver driver;
    String hubUrl = "http://12.11.14.15:4444/wd/hub";

    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeClass() throws MalformedURLException {
        DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(hubUrl), capability);
        Page.setUp(driver);  //Page is the base class of all page objects.
                             //The static setUp method assign a WebDriver object 
                             //to static Page.driver, which shared by all pages.
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void afterClass() {
        driver.quit();
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        driver.get("http://12.11.15.16");
        LoginPage login = new LoginPage();
        login.setUp();                  // set up the Login Page
        login.txtUsername().clear();    //clear the username input box
        login.txtUsername().sendKeys("username");    // input user name
        // ...
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        driver.get("http://12.11.15.16");
        LoginPage login = new LoginPage();
        login.setUp();
        login.txtUsername().clear();
        login.txtUsername().sendKeys("username");
        // ...
    }
}
```

I use selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar for the hub and nodes.

Answer (score 7):

The behaviour you are seeing is correct.

The driver is created in @beforeClass and this is only executed once, therefore only one browser is created which is used by both tests concurrently.

If you were to change to @beforeMethod, then a browser would be created per test BUT this would still fail as the same variable (driver) is being used to store the driver instance. You would see two browsers open but both tests executing in the second.

To run parallel at a test level then you need to ensure each test is entirely encapsulated such as creating its own driver within its own context, and this would not allow you use set up and tear down.

Usually I would always run parallel at class level, as this approach allows you to still use set up and tear down to create the driver instance.  I would recommend changing your XML to run parallel=classes. Obviously you have to have multiple classes but I assume in reality you have more then two tests to run!

Comment: I added some statements like `System.out.println("method name : " + driver)"`, the output showed that the @beforeClass method executed twice, and the webdriver objects in each method were different too. When I changed parallel to `classes`, it turned out that the testes executed successively: test2 first, test1 only started when test2 finished. But you do give me the clue for solving this problem, and now I recognize the reason: all my pageobjects share a same static WebDriver from their parent class `Page`, `Page.driver` was reassigned a new value each time the beforeClass method executed.

Comment: Cool, I must have been wrong in assuming beforeClasd executed twice and apologies for that.  I missed the static property as that was the first thing a looked for but noticed the driver variable wasn't static so stopped at that.  I still think you would be better running per class although still have several tests per class, as this will avoid future issues. Also, passing the driver to page objects as a constructor is probably the best way to go as well

Comment: This is the same answer I gave.  Basically suggesting use of 'class level'.

Comment: Yes, I know you didn't downvote me.  No worries.  I think it was the guy that asked the question.  A great way to get help eh, by downvoting people who try to help.

Answer (score 0):

I would put **test1()** in one class and put **test2()** in a separate class instead of trying to parallelize by method.  Then, TestNG will have no problem forking it.  Just [look at how I did it here](http://djangofan.github.io/simple-selenium-builder-framework/).

If you are wanting to fork by method, it can be done but it is much trickier to configure in TestNG.  I personally have never got it work.  When I try parallel by method, it doesn't seem to do anything for me... it acts the same as parallel by classes.  I know that it is just a matter of configuration though.

In fact, I was recently experiementing in this area [in this project](https://github.com/djangofan/testng-parallel-example) but I remain unsatisfied as to how it ultimately works.

Of course, you probably already know this, you need to make sure you have configured your Grid Node to support 2 or more threads, otherwise it will be constrained to the default value ( 1?) even though you are explicitly forking.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem because a static WebDriver driver. After removed the static call the parallel="tests" worked fine;

Try to remove your private call and execute the same configuration.